# No connection xampp mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I want to link the php file to the database, but I face this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\start\hello.php on line 3

But I don't see any problems in the file.
File data:

```
<?php

    if (mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","university")) {
        echo "yes";
    }
```

But the information is correct.
Please help.***

Comment: is the mysql server actually running?

Comment: This information indicates the MySQL stop!
Check the xamp application

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.  Is mysql on? Is it blocked by firewall? Did you change xampp apache server port in config settings? Can you update us the things you have tried?

Comment: I suspect your mysql server is running on a different port try to add a port to the IP address `127.0.0.1:portNo` unfortunately i can't know the port but if you go to phpMyAdmin it will show you the port.

Comment: Are you sure there is no password? Are you sure that MySQL is running? Are you sure that the port you use is correct? Have you tried connecting to MySQL via CLI?